# How are interface auto-properties implemented in object expressions

Tags: f#

In the following example, what goes in place of the ???:

```
type IFace =
    abstract MyProp : bool with get, set

let createImplementation () =
    { new IFace with
        member this.MyProp = ??? }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is a bit weird. You have to define getter and setter separately and separate them with `and`:

```
let createImplementation () =
    { new IFace with
        member this.MyProp 
            with get() = true
            and set x = () 
    }
```

But of course, such property is kinda useless, because the setter doesn't do anything. It doesn't have anywhere to put the value.

How you handle this depends on what your implementation is supposed to be. One way, the most straightforward I can think of, is to just declare a mutable storage for the property:

```
let createImplementation () =
    let mutable myProp_Value = true
    { new IFace with
        member this.MyProp 
            with get() = myProp_Value
            and set x = myProp_Value <- x
    }
```